# React Native Not able show / display Table inside a Flat list

Tags: react-native, react-hooks

**My results contain a JSON** I have used the concept of props to get the results from a different page. and results contains the following data shown below.

```
 [
    {
        "created_ts": "2020-03-30T23:51:56.280531",
        "description": "Timestamp\n\"2020-03-27T10:33:20.798318638+00:00\"\nError Log\n\"DatabaseError: Unknown error\\n\"\nLink\nhttps://eslogs.prod.dna.rr-it.com/_plugin/kibana/app/kibana#/discover?_g=%28refreshInterval:%28pause:!t,value:0%29,time:%28from:now-15d,to:now%29%29&_a=%28columns:!%28message,kubernetes.labels.job-name%29,index:d3b516c0-eb8c-11e9-8e90-f70ee6010b8a,interval:auto,query:%28language:lucene,query:%27kubernetes.container_name.keyword:shopstyle-dw-visit-shopping-order-load%20AND%20message:error%2A%27%29,sort:!%28%27@timestamp%27,desc%29%29\n",
        "id": 1,
        "incident_ticket_id": "131570",
        "job_last_commit_person": "naga.gswa",
        "job_name": "shopstyle_dw_visit_shopping_order_load",
        "job_owner": "vkramashae",
        "job_type": "spark",
        "last_modified_ts": "2020-03-30T23:51:56.280538",
        "on_call_person": "=rahulu.rk@face.com",
        "severity": "P3",
        "status": "To Do",
        "team_id": 2,
        "tracking_ticket_id": "DE-445474"
    }
]
```

Not able to Display the Api data in table format.I tried the following approach but its not working  and i want to work dynamically can someone tell a solution how to fix this.

```
import React from 'react';
    import {
      View,
      Text,
      StyleSheet,
      FlatList,
      TouchableOpacity,
      ScrollView
    } from 'react-native';
    import { Table, TableWrapper, Row, Rows, Col,Cell } from 'react-native-table-component';


    const ResultsList = ({title , results}) => {

      const head = ['','incident_ticket_id','job_last_commit_person','job_name']

      return (
        <ScrollView style={{marginTop:10}} >
                <ScrollView horizontal={true}>
                    <View style={styles.containerT}>
                        <FlatList
                        datavalue={results}
                        style={{flex:1,marginVertical:20}}
                        renderItem={({item}) =>
                        {

                          return<View style={styles.container}>
                              <Table borderStyle={{borderWidth: 1}}>
                                <Row data={head} flexArr={[1, 2, 1, 1]} style={<styles.head/>} textStyle={styles.text}/>

                                  <Row flexArr={[2, 1, 1]} style={styles.row} textStyle={styles.text}>
                                    <Cell>{item.id}</Cell>
                                    <Cell>{item.incident_ticket_id}</Cell>
                                    <Cell>{item.job_last_commit_person}</Cell>
                                    <Cell>{item.job_last_commit_person}</Cell>
                                  </Row>
                              </Table>
                            </View>
                        }}
                        numColumns={1}
                        />

                    </View>
                </ScrollView>
            </ScrollView>
      );
    };

    const styles = StyleSheet.create({
      title: {
        fontSize: 18,
        fontWeight: 'bold',
        marginLeft: 15,
        marginBottom: 5
      },
      container: { flex: 1, padding: 16, paddingTop: 30, backgroundColor: '#fff' },
      head: {  height: 40,  backgroundColor: '#f1f8ff'  },
      wrapper: { flexDirection: 'row' },
      title: { flex: 1, backgroundColor: '#f6f8fa' },
      row: {  height: 28  },
      text: { textAlign: 'center' }
    });
```

Comment: Did you try logging your api? So you are sure that you have passed it to your new screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the things you are doing right the only thing is in your FlatList you are passing a prop as datavalue it should be data.

Change

```
<FlatList
     datavalue={results}
```

to

```
<FlatList
     data={results}
```

The other thing you are passing whole table inside the FlatList you should only pass the rows, specify the specific width to each row.

And in your case you don't need to use FlatList you can do like this

```
const ResultsList = ({title , results}) => {
    
    const head = ['','incident_ticket_id','job_last_commit_person','job_name']
    // Here I am using tabledata to store rows
    const tableData=[];
        for(var i=0;i<results.length;i++){
            tableData[i]=[results[i].id,results[i].incident_ticket_id,results[i].job_last_commit_person,results[i].job_last_commit_person];
           
        }
//Using widthArr as the column and row should occupy same width
   const  widthArr= [40, 60, 80, 100]
     return (
            <ScrollView style={{marginTop:10}} >
                    <ScrollView horizontal={true}>
                        <View style={styles.containerT}>
                        <View style={styles.container}>
                                  <Table borderStyle={{borderWidth: 1}}>
                                    <Row data={head} widthArr={widthArr} flexArr={[1, 2, 1, 1]} style={<styles.head/>} textStyle={styles.text}/>
                                    <Rows flexArr={[1, 2, 1, 1]} widthArr={widthArr} data={tableData} textStyle={styles.text}/>
                                  </Table>
                                </View>
                        </View>
                    </ScrollView>
                </ScrollView>
          );
        };
```

[image]

I am passing the same object two times by just changing the id in the second object to 2.

Hope this helps!

Comment: where does table come from?